# Part of my object is black

Tags: mesh, shaders, lighting

[image: This is one mesh. Why the 2 different colors? shading? lighting?]

I don't know how I did this. Can someone explain. Is this lighting? shading? why the extreme black and how do I fix this? Thank you. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Normals are probably flipped on this object: Select this object, enter in Edit mode, select all those black faces, hit ctrl N, it should fix it